# Find the probability that the magnitude of the difference of its coordinates is at most 2.

Tags: probability

A point is chosen at random from the circle centered at the origin and with radius 2. Let the random variables X and Y represent the x-coordinate and y-coordinate of the point,respectively. Find the probability that the magnitude of the difference of its coordinates is at most 2.

Comment: This condition defines a region in the circle. Divide its area by the area of the circle. It may help to draw it first.

Comment: I can't figure out the problem.I need a detailed solution

Comment: The region is bounded by the lines $y-x=2$ and $y-x=-2$. Can you draw them?

Comment: The region bounded by the line y-x = 2 and y-x = -2 are two right triangles inside the circle. The area of those two triangles are 4 square units. Therefore the probability is 4 / 4pi  or 1/pi. Is this correct?

Comment: Now I thought it would be more than that.

Comment: The shape those two lines cut out of a circle is *not* a pair of triangles.

Comment: It's a semi circle plus 2 right triangles.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the magnitude of the difference to be at most $2$ then you need the area of the region $|x-y|<2$ and intersect with the circle of radius $2$. Note that the region $|x-y|<2$ is the region bounded by the lines $x-y=2$ and $x-y=-2$. With some geometry you can see that the area is $4 \pi  - 2(\pi - 2)= 2 \pi + 4$ then the probability is $\dfrac{2 \pi + 4}{4 \pi} = \dfrac{\pi + 2}{2 \pi}$.